# checking speed and memory size of a c# method

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-analysis

Does anyone see any issues with this basic test?

```
var GC_MemoryStart = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
var test = new InquiryServiceTypeData().GetActive(true);
stopWatch.Stop();
var GC_MemoryEnd = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
arrayTotal[i] = (stopWatch.ElapsedTicks * 1000.0) / Stopwatch.Frequency;
size[i] = GC_MemoryEnd - GC_MemoryStart;
```

Just trying to get a general estimate of how long the method takes to run and how much memory in the heap it uses.

Aka, some of the tests use dataset/datatables, some use lists, and some use both.

This code is thrown in a loop so that I can change the number of iterations. I then display the average time each method takes and the average size.

EDIT: The GetActive method accesses a database and returns data. The different methods that I'm measuring process the data returned in a different way.

Method 1 - Returns a data into a dataset and then converts to an object list.
Method 2 - Returns a datareader and converts to an object list.
Method 3 - A merging of the first 2 methods.

The reason for the code is to settle a disagrement with a coworker. He thinks my code was crap because the datareader and converting to an object list has a ton of 'new' statements which places a load on the heap. I argue that he's wrong. So I want to show him metrics because he didn't listen to any of my logical statements. You can't argue with numbers though.

Comment: What exactly is the idea behind the memory test? To clarify: the code may create long-lived objects, and it may also create ref type instances that are intended to be discarded. What do you want to measure?

Comment: a disagreement with a coworker. He says that my code was crap and that you should do it his way because it uses less memory on the heap.

Comment: BTW, the DataReader method will be faster.

Comment: I know that, which is why I rewrote it. But he still rewrote all my code back to the way it was using a datatable and wouldn't listen to any of my arguments. So I thought, maybe I'm wrong and he's right. Let's test it and find out. But before I showed him, thought it might be a good idea to make sure I was testing it correctly.

Comment: amazingly, his code is slightly faster (which surprises me to no end, but mine takes half the size in the memory. It's only bringing back a small amount of data, so I'm going to retest with something that brings back more than 5 rows....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty good.

However, you should call the method once before you time anything so that you don't end up timing the JITter.

Comment: can you show me an example of what you're asking? I'm not 100% sure what you I'm supposed to do.

Comment: @Cyfer13: Just call the method once before you time it.

Comment: well, that was pretty easy and really dumb of me to ask now that I reread what you said....

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [ANTS Performance Profiler 6.3](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

It is extremely easy to install and use. So you can improve your .NET code quickly.